# There exists a a metric space such that its group of isometries is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, isometry

My question is as follows: I have to choose true or false. This is a question from a Graduate
school admission test.

There exists   a metric space such that its group of isometries is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Is it true?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\mathbb{Z}$ is the symmetry group of what?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2394650/mathbbz-is-the-symmetry-group-of-what)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

The solution of @MathematicsStudent1122 is quite salvageable, just consider the space
$$\mathbb{Z} \cup (\mathbb{Z}+ \frac{1}{3})\cup (\mathbb{Z}+\frac{1}{2})$$

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: it is basically your idea +  a symmetry break

Comment: Thanks! This is great

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: It was still not right, needed another translate to break the symmetry, now I think it's OK. It's basically one of the frieze patterns.

Comment: can someone please elaborate a little further